# associated homogeneous linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, homogeneous-equation

Can someone please explain how  associated homogeneous linear differential equations work with an example?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have the linear differential equation
$y'' + y =3x$;

The associated homogeneous equation is
$y'' + y = 0$

The set of the solutions to the homogeneous equation is {$\alpha \cos  +\beta \sin ; \alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R$}.

One particular solution to the innitial equation is 3x.

Thus theset of solutions to the initial equation is {$\alpha \cos x +\beta \sin x + 3x; \alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R$}.